# Typing and `nonrec` in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a puzzling example, the "ok" below, which I don't understand completely.

```ml
module File1_intf = struct
  type type1 = { nat : int }

  module type Intf = sig
    type nonrec type1 = type1
  end
end

module File1 : File1_intf.Intf = struct
  include File1_intf
end

module File3 = struct
  open File1

  let ok : type1 -> type1 = fun { nat } -> { nat = 0 }
  let ko { nat (*Unbound record field nat*) } = { nat = 0 }
end
```

I expect the "unbound record field", but I wonder why adding a type decoration bring the field "nat" into scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation `File1.type1` = `File_intf.type1` is in scope in the ok function. Thus type-directed disambiguation can expand the abbreviation of `File1.type1` to disambiguate the field `nat`.

The compiler does warn you that the field `nat` itself is not in scope:

```
Warning 40: this record of type File1_intf.type1 contains fields
that are not visible in the current scope: nat.
They will not be selected if the type becomes unknown.
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about type-directed disambiguation.